# How to ownership-transfer inherited securities from a foreign brokerage?

Tags: united-states, stocks, international, transfer

I have inherited a set of stocks that sit on the Swedish Stock exchange (in an Avanza brokerage) from a deceased relative. The stocks are still currently in the name/ownership of the still-living spouse. I am a dual US/German citizen who resides in the US. Ideally I would like to transfer the stocks directly from this brokerage to my brokerage, without selling them and transferring in cash to avoid a taxable event. The brokerages I have access to refuse to do this for a variety of reasons (my primary residence, international transfer issues, audit/money laundering considerations, etc...). Is this legal? Is there a simple way to do to this? Do I just need to find a brokerage that allows for this sort of thing? Is there no other way other than liquidating and gifting or transferring?